# Suddenly web app no longer shows developer exception page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, development-environment

I am developing a MVC webapp in ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. All is well so far, except that, since the last couple of days, errors in the application are no longer handled by the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`. The environment is 'Development'. I tried to 'comment out' that instruction in 'Startup.cs' to see if the default "/Home/Error" page would display, but that doesn't work either, so it seems that errors aren't handled... Period!

What happens basically is that the browser never moves away from the page where I sent the last request (but it doesn't freeze/crash either) and if I want to know what happened I need to look at the output window of the ASP.Net Core Web Server in VS2017.

Behaviour is the same irrespective of whether I am running in Debug mode or Run-without-debug-mode.
Obviously, I didn't intentionally do anything to achieve this... Any idea of what would cause this or what I should be looking at?

Here is the Startup.cs:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
> using WebApp.Data;
> using WebApp.Models;
> using WebApp.Services;
>
> namespace WebApp {
> public class Startup
> {
>     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
>     {
>         Configuration = configuration;
>     }
>
>     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
>
>     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
>     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>     {
>         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
>             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
>
>         services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
>             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
>             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
>
>         // Add application services.
>         services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
>
>         services.AddMvc();
>
>         services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Account>, GenericRepository<Account>>();
>         services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Period>, GenericRepository<Period>>();
>         services.AddScoped<Report>();
>     }
>
>     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
>     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
>     {
>         if (env.IsDevelopment())
>         {
>             app.UseBrowserLink();
>             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>             app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
>         }
>
>         app.UseStaticFiles();
>
>         app.UseAuthentication();
>
>         app.UseMvc(routes =>
>         {
>             routes.MapRoute(
>                 name: "default",
>                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
>         });
>     }
> } }
> ```

And this is the launchSettings.json:

```js
{
 "iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
   "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64904/",
   "sslPort": 44374
  }
 },
 "profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
   "commandName": "IISExpress",
   "launchBrowser": true,
   "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44374/",
   "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   }
  },
  "WebApp": {
   "commandName": "Project",
   "launchBrowser": true,
   "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   },
   "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64905/"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: could you show an example of controller/middleware/whatever that raises an exception?

Comment: @Set As I was getting the data to answer your question, it occurred to me that the problem started when I changed some methods from synchronous to asynchronous, and the errors where in the latter, so the handler was never triggered as the action simply kept waiting...

Comment: @Set Thanks for offering to help anyway. I feel a bit !Smart ;)

Comment: While you may have solved *this* issue, that bit about the action hanging waiting on an async operation is troubling. I'd suggest opening a new question regarding that, and include all the code related to that. It sounds like you're not doing something right there, and you might end up with deadlocks or other nastiness, as a result.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You're absolutely right. That actually raised another problem, which I've been trying to address since I started this post, i.e. the exception is thrown by the web server (so I can see it in the web server output in VS) but it is not handled by the try-catch in the code, which should result in the error page being displayed. I will post in another thread as I can't seem to find the solution. Thanks